How/Where Can I Disable this Amazon S3 Cloudwatch Service?
I'm not even sure where that Data goes, and I already use a service that tracks all my S3 usage, so I'd like to disable these Cloudwatch services, but I don't know where or how.
I have looked through my console, but I don't see a reference to cloudwatch or anything similar.
I understand that Cloudwatch can't be disabled as such, but I believe you can turn off the data sending, but where is the option to?
Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.


You'll need to check inside cloudwatch in that region ( https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-east-1#home: ) which metrics it has and what would write them. For S3 Metrics you'll find information here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/cloudwatch-monitoring.html (those are not turned on by default afaik)
